# Unable to load websites for unknown reasons

Tags: windows-8, dns, internet-connection

I'm using Windows 8 on my laptop, and I'm occasionally having trouble loading websites for the past 3 months.

It starts with the websites taking a longer time to load than usual. Then they will stop loading completely after an hour or so. I've tried with Firefox and Chrome, and on Chrome, I just get the "Resolving host" message at the left bottom corner for a long time, while there is no message at all in Firefox.

I thought it was a DNS issue because I could ping IP addresses but not domain names, and did the following before restarting the PC, but it didn't help.

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
pconfig /renew
netsh int ip set dns
netsh winsock reset
```

I also disabled the "Hardware-assisted virtualization" option in my Avast (I also have MalwareBytes), which also didn't help.

But after a day or two, I would be able to load websites again. It just happened again yesterday morning, and without doing anything (other than shutting down last night and booting it up this morning), I was able to load websites again.

One thing I could think of was when I was able to load websites again, the "Duration" value of my Wireless connection was reset. The picture below shows the current "Duration" value, 14+ hours. It was 12 days and 22+ hours yesterday when the problem occurred, and 19 days+ when the problem occurred the previous time.

[image: "Duration" reset after websites started loading again]

Another thing was after I was able to load websites again, Avast would tell me it has performed an application update. I think this happened the last time too.

I am still able to access the Internet using my other mobile devices, and only have problems with this laptop.

I'm puzzled as to why this problem occurs. Is it Avast, or would resetting the "Duration" help? If so, how can I reset the value?

Comment: If the error occurs again, you could try the Diagnose button. It can sometimes give useful diagnostic info. Also, you could try manually specifying DNS servers. I haven't tried that for IPv6 but if you're using IPv4, you could try setting DNS to one of the Comodo Secure DNS IP Addresses, for example, or Google DNS such as: 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4. If you think you're having trouble with Avast, try a different AV if possible. If you're using free AV, you may try Avira or BitDefender Free or AVG.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried the Diagnose button, but it didn't really give any useful output (IIRC, it was just stuck at diagnosing). I've also tried to set the DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but that didn't work either.